# Two dynamic segments in one pathname?

Tags: next.js

When you have the following path with two dynamic segments, for EG:

./pages/pipelines/[pipelineId]/builds/[buildId].tsx

And you use something like this in your javascript/typescript - in a hook function:

router.query.buildId?.toString() || null;

...how does nextjs routing know what pipelineId to use? And how does it find its way deeper into the filesystem hierarchy - that is, how does it know to skip the earlier path components?

I googled for about a half day, but didn't find any relevant hits.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm now thinking I had it backwards: this isn't going to a route, it's accepting input from a route.

Answer (score 0):

I'm now thinking I had it backwards: this isn't going to a route, it's accepting input from a route.